# Why might a breakpoint not break the code execution?

Tags: c#

I encountered a problem.

I noticed that a Property (say `MyProp`) in my program is being invoked continuously by the main thread. In spite of a breakpoint is inserted at its get accessor scope, the code isn't broken at that point! (Why?)

So I couldn't check the call stack to find out which part of my code is invoking that property on and on. I tried to chack the stack trace manually as follows:

```
public static MyType MyProp {
    get {
        string threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        string MTID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        Debug.WriteLine("» MyProp");
        Debug.Indent();
        Debug.WriteLine("Current Thread : MTID = " + MTID + ", Name = " + threadName);

        StackTrace stack = new StackTrace();
        Debug.WriteLine("Frame Count : " + stack.FrameCount);

        for (int index = 0; index < stack.FrameCount; index++)
        {
            StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(index);
            string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Frame [{0}]: Method = '{1}'", index + 1, methodName));
        }
        Debug.Unindent();

        // Rest of code..
    }
}
```

Also, I searched the `MyProp` symbol in entire solution and then used the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` method wherever this property is invoked, but none of them is written at the Output window!! (How could this be possible?)

By pressing F11 key, (i.e. to start my prog from the very beginning point) and right after required dll-s were loaded, I see the following lines in the Output window:

```
'MyProg.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System....dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
:
'MyProg.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\My Prog\bin\Debug\MyProg.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MyProg.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\My Prog\bin\Debug\part1.dll', Symbols loaded.
:
'MyProg.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\My Prog\bin\Debug\partn.dll', Symbols loaded.
» MyProp
    Current Thread : MTID = '9', Name = '' // <- Main thread
    Frame Count : 6
    Frame [1]: Method = 'get_MyProp' // <- How???
    Frame [2]: Method = 'Main'
    Frame [3]: Method = '_nExecuteAssembly'
    Frame [4]: Method = 'RunUsersAssembly'
    Frame [5]: Method = 'Run'
    Frame [6]: Method = 'ThreadStart'
```

The annoying thing is that every once I go one step ahead (By pressing F10 or F11 key), I see the `» MyProp` log section again!!!

What could be causeing this and how can I treat this issue? _Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to get all callers?

If you have **ReSharper** you can get all call stacks without debugging by placing cursor on your property and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Alt+A* and selecting ***Incoming Calls***. (See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Call_Tracking.html).

Here is an example of *Inspection Results* view:
[image]

Or just use **Visual Studio built-in feature: *Call Hierarchy***. Right-click member and select *View Call Hierarchy*. Example view:

[image]

### How to set break point within properties?

Update1: I can debug into properties on my machine (VS2010). My debugging options are:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I pressed _Shift+F12_ and _Shift+Alt+F12_ in Visual Studio to find all of its references. Can ReSharper help more?

I Disabled _Step over properties and operators_ option, but my problem steel persist!

Comment: I added screenshots for ReSharper's *Inspection Results* and VS's *Call Hierarchy*. Their advantage over searching references is the hierarchical structure. You see the whole call stack at once.

Comment: I added screenshots of my debug options. Maybe you can see differences to your options. And as you see it works also with **enabled** *Step over properties and operators (Managed only)* setting.

Comment: I renamed the `MyProp` to some other name (say `MyProp1`). The last version of my software works with no problem using `MyProp`. Therefore, I really don't understand why, but it works all right now.

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to tell what could cause your property to be accessed multiple times without more code.

For now, I would recommend adding

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

in your getter, which will break your program in the debugger when executed. Then look at the stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Break` method could not break it too!

Comment: Is it possible if this property is invoked by one of visual studio debugger threads and if so, how to detect it?